# How do I build a mixed x axis for histogram in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot the finishing time of a process that occasionally fails.  All but one of my buckets for the histogram would be numeric.  How can I add a "fail" or time is nan bucket to my histogram?

My work so far plots both, but I lose the numeric x labels.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

time = np.random.uniform(size = 1000)
fail = time > 0.95

d = pd.DataFrame(time)
d.loc[fail,0] = np.nan
d['fail'] = np.isnan(d.loc[:,0])

ax = d[0].hist()
ax.bar(x=1.5,height=d['fail'].sum(),color='r',tick_label='Fail')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `ax.bar()` replaces the numeric ticks with one tick on the new bar. I don't know if there's a recommended way to handle this, but I was able to manually set the ticks with [`set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels). I left one major tick as you currently have it, and then added minor ticks for the numeric bins.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

time = np.random.uniform(size = 1000)
fail = time > 0.95

d = pd.DataFrame(time)
d.loc[fail,0] = np.nan
d['fail'] = np.isnan(d.loc[:,0])

ax = d[0].hist()
ax.bar(left=1.5,height=d['fail'].sum(),color='r',tick_label='Fail')

minor_ticks = [x/5 for x in range(6)]
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(minor_ticks, minor=True)

plt.show()
```

I also had to change your `ax.bar(x=...)` to `ax.bar(left=...)`. I don't know if that was a mistake or just a version difference.

Here's what my plot looks like:

[image: example plot]